# Get asset count per Account

Tags: soql

I need to get Account names and asset count for each account. 
From Asset table I can get AccountId and asset count. 
But I need to get Account names also. This is where I stuck. 
How to use Ids, from aggregate query and get Account names by Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want non-aggregated fields from records identified through an aggregate query, you need to make a second, non-aggregate, SOQL query.

For example.

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregateResults = [
    SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) amt
    FROM Opportunity
    GROUP BY AccountId
];
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for (AggregateResult ar : aggregateResults) {
    accountIds.add(ar.get('AccountId'));
}
```

then, to get the names of the grouped objects,

```
Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account(
    [SELECT Name
     FROM Account
     WHERE Id IN :accountIds]
);
```

The Map then makes it easy to connect from the aggregate data to the parent record information. Adapting these example queries to the scenario described above should be straightforward.